# Navigation bar position disturbed in after review alert

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

While going through first post review queue, I edited a post and SO presented an alert after the edit that an updated was already made to this post. After closing the alert above top navigation bar, the space gets empty and top navigation stays out of position. Screenshot attached.

[image: Out of position nav bar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny thing, this bug has nothing to do with *either* the new top bar *or* the review queue. In fact, it may be older than either of the two. It's just much more visible now, and especially so in the review page.

Fixed in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: We all get weird scenarios in our day to day development