# Buggy behavior with sticky menu + notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav, notifications

SO's notification popups don't play nice with a sticky menu:

When the notification is shown,

- The whole page is pushed down as much as the notification's height.

  - (Even if you're scrolled down, when the notification is sticky.)
- The notification appears above the menu if you're at the top of the page.
- The notification disappears *behind* the menu, if you scroll down a little bit.

I'd expect the notification to be stuck to the top of the page, *over* the menu.
I'd expect it not to move the whole page around.

Scrolled to top:

> [image]

Scrolled down a little, the menu moves up and over the notification:

> [image]

Code to make a message appear:

```
StackExchange.notify.show("TestMessage", "foo");
```

Comment: Noticed that the message doesn't go off when clicked on `x`(close) button on right.

Comment: @Tushar: That's probably because of the "quick-and-dirty" test code. It probably needs some more parameters. Edited the question with a little disclaimer explaining that)

Comment: Ohh. I thought that's complete code. And as `x` is shown, I was expecting it to work by default.

Comment: Try `StackExchange.notify.show("TestMessage", "foo")` (any notification needs a MessageTypeId for the `x` to work).

Comment: Thanks, @balpha! That works.

Comment: Similar issue: [Navigation bar position disturbed in after review alert](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343826/2675154)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two (and a half) points work as intended (and are identical to the behavior with the old top bar). The thirds was indeed a bug and is fixed in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, fair enough :-) I wasn't sure how it originally behaved. Thanks for the quick response!